# Running author, title etc. for beamer slide using pandoc

Tags: beamer, header-footer, pandoc, front-matter

In the `beamer` class, front matter commands such as `author` and `title` have optional parameters for short versions to be shown in slide headers or footers. Is there an easy way to obtain this when using `pandoc` to compose `beamer` slides?

For example, my YAML preamble currently reads something like the following:

```
title: Title of My Talk
author:
  - My Name\inst{1}
  - Coauthor's Name\inst{2}
institute:
  - \inst{1}University of Somewhere
  - \inst{2}University of Elsewhere
date: Seminar date
```

but I would like something short like "M. Name & C. Name (Somewhere & Elsewhere)" to appear on slide footers, instead of the whole thing. Is there any way to obtain that, hopefully without changing the `pandoc` template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the actual latex macros with this little trick:

```
--- 
title: Title of My Talk
author:
  - My Name\inst{1}
  - Coauthor's Name\inst{2}
institute:
  - \inst{1}University of Somewhere
  - \inst{2}University of Elsewhere
date: Seminar date
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: Dresden
header-includes:
   - \AtBeginDocument{\author[short version for footline]{long version for title page}}
---
 
 test
```

[image]

(as these macros will only take effect after the start of the document, they won't be included in the pdf meta data, this will still be generated from the rmarkdown fields)

Comment: Great, thanks! I might wait a few days for "cleaner" solutions before accepting, but this works absolutely fine.